# Delay to show Laucher screen on boot?

Tags: android, launcher, wallpaper, homescreen

I build an custom Home launcher which have some scree before to show Live wallpaper/wallpaper screen. Problem here is before to show launcher scree it show wallpaper set on device for a moment then it show launcher screen.

Does any have idea about what can be issue?

Comment: Post your code and brief your question more.

Comment: GrIsHu: it's simple dear. On boot, before to show screen of launcher, system show wallpaper screen for a moment then La.Screen display...got idea?

Comment: Even simpler, copy+paste your code here.

Comment: it's just another launcher app with some screen ahead of Live wallpaper screen(WS)...or u can say over to WS before to show it.