# Android Architecture to show Wallpaper/Live Wallpaper?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, launcher

I am trying to implement Live Wallpaper related stuff in my custom launcher([have some issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19628857/2624806)).
Does anybody have any guide line to understand me to how Android layer architecture design for Live wallpaper, how it communicate with Launcher app?

Comment: what's wrong here...suggest something with doing down voting..that will be more useful.

Comment: I don't understand these stupid people too - voting down a question but don't have an answer/idea/hint for it is really poor...